# Exporting avatars from Daz3D, fbx to Unity material conflict

Tags: unity-game-engine, fbx, daz3d

I am having an issue in exporting models from Daz3D to Unity.

When I export as fbx from Daz3D then import to Unity some of the items have the wrong textures.
I figured out that the issue is if you have 2 items in Daz3D with the same name for a surface in Unity these get imported into the Assests/Materials directories, but if 2 surfaces have the same name Unity overwrites the file when it imports. (I assume it overwrites on import, could also be Daz overwriting on export I guess, but less likely).

Any idea of a workaround?

I also tried using the Unity Bridge in Daz3D, and its seems to work correctly, and creates _1 files names on conflicts. But with Unity Bridge the files sizes are too big and crashes some consoles/phones. Also does not work easily with older Unity versions (2018).

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a workaround at least. I export the clothing that conflicts as a seperate fbx, then drag/drop the material in Unity into the avatars clothing item in the scene. This overwrites the wrong material it was getting.

If anyone know how to reduce the fbx size for the Unity Bridge please reply, it exports about 2x the normal fbx export size.